# Elasticsearch MasterNotDiscoveredException between client and master

Tags: elasticsearch

In a nutshell, I have a standalone ES master instance and a client node that is created within my Java application. The client node discovers the standalone ES instance correctly if the standalone ES instance is started before the client node, which is expected.

The problem I'm facing is this - if for some reason, the client node starts before the standalone ES instance, I see a "MasterNotDiscoveredException", which is again expected. However, I continue seeing the same exception even after I start the standalone ES instance. Is there some configuration I should be changing to fix this?

I'm using ES 1.7.1 with Unicast discovery.

**EDIT**

**Cluster information:** The standalone ES instance and the client node together make up a cluster.

**Client node stack trace:**

```
11:29:35,634 INFO  http [496648366, id=7BCBFQLCTWOO2, ide=tcp://172.17.78.80:61616] [Squidboy] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/172.17.78.80:9200]}
11:29:35,635 INFO  node [496648366, id=7BCBFQLCTWOO2, ide=tcp://172.17.78.80:61616] [Squidboy] started
11:30:10,279 ERROR ApplicationLifeCycle [299961584] System startup not complete after 120 seconds ...
11:30:14,706 WARN  ElasticSearchStatus [278792216] An Exception occurred during cluster health status update - java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.getValue(BaseFuture.java:292)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:279)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:117)
        at com.harry.elastic.node.ElasticSearchStatus.updateClusterHealth(ElasticSearchStatus.java:90)
        at com.harry.elastic.node.ElasticSearchStatus.access$000(ElasticSearchStatus.java:37)
        at com.harry.elastic.node.ElasticSearchStatus$1.run(ElasticSearchStatus.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeOperationAction$4.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeOperationAction.java:164)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:231)
        at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:560)
        ... 3 more
```

**Client creation code**:

```
private Node createEmbeddedClientNode() {
        ImmutableSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false)
                .put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "localhost[9300-9400]");
        return nodeBuilder().settings(settingsBuilder).clusterName("harryService")
                .client(true).data(false).node();
    }
```

**Master discovery configuration**

```
"discovery": {
    "zen": {
      "ping": {
        "multicast": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace you're getting (or better the relevant log portion) and also the client creation code? Also how many nodes do you have in your cluster and how does your unicast configuration look like?

Comment: I've added more detail to the question. Thanks.

Comment: You said your ES cluster was external, right? then how come your `unicast.hosts` settings references `localhost`? Or maybe I misunderstood what "external" means to you...

Comment: Ah, sorry for not being clear. "External", in my case, means that it is not embedded. It is a standalone instance started using `ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch.bat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding unicast configuration in the master node explicitly.

```
"discovery": {
    "zen": {
      "ping": {
        "multicast": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "unicast": {
            "hosts": "localhost[9300-9400]"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default your client node will retry pinging your master node each 30s for 3 times and then give up. So if you started your master node after that time has passed, your client node will not discover it.

Try increasing the retries and/or the timeout, that should help.

```
.put("discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout", "1m")
.put("discovery.zen.fd.ping_retries", 5)
```

With those settings, your client node will keep trying during 5 minutes instead of only 1.5 minutes. However, your master node should really be up already when you start your application.

Another settings that might help is the following, as it is true by default and your master will ignore client pings during master election, but since there's a single master node it might not make any difference, still worth a try:

```
.put("discovery.zen.master_election.filter_client", false)
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this out?

Comment: Hey Val, this doesn't work for me. I tried starting up my ES instance right after the first occurrence of the MasterNotDiscoveredException, but that too didn't stop the exceptions from re-occurring. As a result, I'm now looking at ways of shutting the application if it encounters a MasterNotDiscovered exception. Thanks for your help :)