# Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::ServiceUnavailable ([503] {"error":"MasterNotDiscoveredException[waited for [30s]]","status":503}):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install but , i cant get solution for this error: -

> ([503] {"error":"MasterNotDiscoveredException[waited for
>   [30s]]","status":503})

i'm stuck in this, however i also tried some solution given on internet but it did not work for me. any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878284/elasticsearch-masternotdiscoveredexception-between-client-and-master) might help

Comment: @PetIbaño not sure where should i write that configuration as i m using ubuntu system.

Comment: I think you should revert things and start again. There's a lot of things to check when you're using elasticsearch. First make sure you have java running. Then elasticsearch engine compatible with what java version you use. You might also want to check your machine memory because elastic needs a lot of it to be stable. Also make sure to configure elasticsearch port. I hope this helps.

Comment: Btw, you might want to check [searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), its using elasticsearch as search engine.